# Javascript not working inside a PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm new to javascript.

There seems to be no result but a blank screen when I try the following code:

```
function send_to_class($data)
{
echo 'PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP';
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(".username").append(<?php echo $data;?>); 
        </script>
    <?php
echo 'EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE';
}
```

and my PHP

```
$data = "You might think I'm Bonkers, but I just think I'm Free";
send_to_class($data);
```

and my html

```
<span class="username"></span>
```

1. The Function is declared before the send_to_class($data) is initiated.
2. The P's and the E's are showing up just fine, there's just no middle sentence.
3. I've tried divs, id's and classes, adding css and changing the script tag.

2 things, a) how do I get the function to work which appends $data to the .username class and b) how do I get it to work if $data is an array? Can Javascript print php arrays in this manner?

Thanks.

Comment: `$(".username").append(<?php echo $data;?>);` needs to be `$(".username").append('<?php echo $data;?>');` or `$(".username").append("<?php echo $data;?>");`. and make sure jQuery library is added

Comment: *"I'm new to javascript."* . then start on good foot and don't mix it all up with a server side language. The two run in completely different places and at different times

Comment: I need the interoperability. And yea Alive -I saw that just now. I tried adding "" 's to the script, but it still seems to not work. How does one normally go about using php and javascript in this fashion? Have I got the script tags right? Here is my library: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>. Will that work with this kind of Javascript?

Comment: Turn on php error reporting.  If no errors are shown, check view/source in your browser, are you getting “ppppp” anywhere?  If yes, check your browser developer tools console for errors.

Comment: I used ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); on all 3 pages and had no errors displayed. I checked for console errors and all javascript seems to be working fine if that's what you mean? I can see in my browser that the script is displaying and that the correct values are inside the javascript. I'm thinking I'm have an old jquery? I don't know which I'm supposed to be running.

Comment: Sorted it. It was because I had the included send_to_class.php file being rendered and executed BEFORE the html DOM was built, and as we know javascript can only manipulate things out of the DOM once it's rendered by the browser. Looks like I'll be running all my php at the bottom of the page.

Comment: What do I do for the answer? Is it good to write it myself or? I heard this pace is a little strict on how people conduct themselves. Do I answer?

Comment: You can answer your own question if you like, or you can edit your question and put the answer there while keeping the question so future people who may have this exact same question knows how or what you did to solve it if they are experiencing the same issue...Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that because the $data I was sending contained "'s that it needed to have the "'s escaped. So in my php file that was producing the data, I had to turn the following:

`<div class="class1">some words</div>`

into this:

`<div class=\"class1\">some words</div>`

This is because it's javascript that's doing the printing, and when javascript does printing of "'s it needs to have them escaped with a backslash like this \".